# Unable to import module from package

Tags: elm

I recently installed Elm's [List.Extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/6.1.0/List-Extra) package.

I am attempting to import the List.Extra module from the package with the following:

```
module Tests.TestAPI exposing (..)

import List.Extra as ListHelper exposing (..)
```

However, I receive the following error:

> - I cannot find module 'List.Extra'.
>
> Module 'Tests.TestAPI' is trying to import it.
>
> Potential problems could be:   * Misspelled the module name   * Need
>   to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json

The List.Extra module looks like the following:

```
module List.Extra
    exposing
        ( last,
          ...
        )
```

Any suggestions on what I need to do to successfully import this module?

Comment: Noting that you are talking about tests, perhaps you installed List.Extra in your main app, but not in the tests directory?

Comment: I resolved it by restarting my IDE.

Comment: @ScottNimrod then either delete this question or add an answer and accept it so that this question appears as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by restarting my IDE (Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer. Otherwise this still won't appear as a solved question.

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't know about this restriction to accepting self-answers. That's too bad, I think.